# Puppeteer page.setRequestInterception didn't catch any requests on iframe

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

I'm crawling data from a page which contains an iframe.
The sample code

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
    console.log(request.url());
    //.........................
    request.continue();
});

await page.goto(url, {waitUtil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 30000});
//..................
```

This code only showed requests on main frame, it couldn't catch any requests from the inner iframe. In Chrome network inspection, I saw many XHR requests from this page.

Is there a way to catch requests on iframe ? Many thanks !

Comment: I tested your code against https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp and it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Maybe it's frame.setRequestInterception ? Just a thought.

Comment: The code didn't work with node9 on windows. I have tried testing the code on Ubuntu. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I set puppeteer headless = true, the above code has worked. It catches all requests on all iframes on my crawling website.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that adding these to browser startup options may fix the problem:

```
args: [
   '--disable-web-security',
   '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'
]
```

**Update 2023**: Seems Puppeteer will remove this in future versions. At the moment you can enable intercepting by adding this extra argument:

```
--disable-site-isolation-trials
```